# Yii: Drop down Widget

Tags: php, yii, widget

I am trying to create a drop down using `widget` in my `Yii` web application. Here is what I am doing:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                        'id' => 'events-grid-future',
                        'filterPosition' => 'footer',
                        //'dataProvider' => $model->search('future'),
                        'dataProvider' => $model->search('future'),
                        'filter' => $model,
                        'ajaxUrl' => array('events/admin', 'search_all' => $search_all_value),
                        'itemsCssClass' => 'table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed',
                        'columns' => array(
                            array(
                                'name' => 'status',
                                'header' => 'Job Status',
                                'value' => 'ucfirst($data->status)',
                                'filter' => array('All' => 'All', 'Enquiry' => 'Enquiry', 'Contract Issued' => 'Contract Issued', 'Confirmed' => 'Confirmed', 'Hold' => 'Hold', 'Performed' => 'Performed'),
                            ),
),
)
```

But the drop down appears to be like this:

[image]

There is a null `key` with null `value`. I want to remove that. any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `'empty' => '--- Select --- '` in filter:

```
'filter' => array('All' => 'All', 'Enquiry' => 'Enquiry', 'Contract Issued' => 'Contract Issued', 'Confirmed' => 'Confirmed', 'Hold' => 'Hold', 'Performed' => 'Performed'),array('empty'=>'--- Select --- ')
```

Comment: tried it with no success, still the null key value appears

Comment: This null value will used for no selection means if you don't want to apply any filter.

Comment: so is there no way to get rid of it?

Comment: if you remove it somehow then your gridview will  be always stay filtered.